# Maven Build Scripts Found - IntelliJ - What are the build scripts, where are they cached?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

So basically, as the title of the post states, I'm wondering what IntelliJ is referring to when it says that Maven build scripts were found? Are these scripts that Maven keeps cached or are they IntelliJ specific? If they are generated by Maven, where are they stored/ how can I view them if that is possible?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This notification is to inform you that you are working with IntelliJ IDEA project that is not linked to the external build system (Maven or Gradle).

When you open a project in IntelliJ IDEA that was not initially imported from Maven/Gradle and IDE detects `pom.xml` or `build.gradle` files in the project, it will display a notification so that you can properly import the project from the build script.

Build script in your specific case is a `pom.xml` file stored inside a project directory. It's [recommended](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/maven-support.html#maven_import_project_start) that you open Maven projects by importing the root `pom.xml` file.

When a project is not imported from the external build system, your source roots configuration may be incomplete and you may be missing the dependencies.